# Suggestions, isporations and ideas for report page for an ERP

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, user-centered-design, experience

I am designing a reports page where users come and fill in the required fields and get the report. They can then choose to download or view the report. Considering that our users are not very tech-savvy we have decided to make the process easier for them by prefilling some of the fields required to get the report. To make the UI look cleaner we have decided to show a minimized version of the fields where the users will have to only fill the most important fields required for the report and the rest of the fields will be prefilled. If the users need to change the other fields they will have to maximise or (see more details) and then make the changes and then view the report.

Any suggestion on how to design the minimized version of the screen which will have both input fields and predefined selections. Also any references for screens like this would. be appreciated.
I will attach an image for reference[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would work on structuring the form elements. Would make them more understandable and cleaner. Below are some examples for inspiration.

[image]
[image]
[image]